# Is there an R function for creating a dataframe in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to create a dataframe in  sidebarlayout. But not to create with this code

```
 library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
 data.frame(a=(1,2),b=c(3,4)),
 mainPanel(h6("This is my dataframe"))
 )
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: for sure you would have to create the dataframe in the `server` but do you just want to display it in the `sidebar` or do you want something else? Here's some example code:
`server <- function(input, output, session) {output$tab=renderTable(data.frame(a=(1,2),b=c(3,4)))}`. `ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout( tableOutput('tab')))`

Comment: i only need to display

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?:

```
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarPanel(tableOutput('tab')),mainPanel())
server <- function(input, output, session) {output$tab=renderTable(data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4)))}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It creates the data frame in the `server`- in the `renderTable` command rather than in the `ui`.